# fortran77 code execution does not stop

Tags: fortran, fortran77

There is a F77 code, slightly modified from me. The code calls a particular routine, but it seems that compilation does not stop (and I believe there is no problem with loops). This  makes me wonder why this might happen.

Second i cannot really understand what the output of that routine will be. Can anyone help here?

this is the section of the code that calls the routine/function. By working a MWE,

```
integer, parameter:: nf=101, ns=7, nas=427, na=61, nxm=3
integer:: i,j,k,     

allocate(xf(nf), xa(na))
allocate(absa(nxm,na-1), wgta(nxm,na-1),absf(nxm,nf-1), wgtf(nxm,nf-1))



    do 150 i=1,na-1
          call qgausl (nxp(i), xa(i), xa(i+1), absa(1,i), wgta(1,i))
 150    continue

       do 160 i=1,nf-1
          call qgausl (nxp(i), xf(i), xf(i+1), absf(1,i), wgtf(1,i))
  160    continue
```

And this is the routine

```
     subroutine qgausl(n,x1,x2,x,w)
      implicit none 
      integer:: n, m
      real*8:: xl,x2, x1, xm, eps, z, p1,p2,p3, pp, z1
      real*8:: x(n), w(n) 

     eps=1.0e-8
       m=(n+1)/2
      xm=0.5*(x2+x1)
      xl=0.5*(x2-x1)

      do 12 i=1,m

        z = cos(3.141592654*(i-.25)/(n+.5))
1       continue
print*, z
          p1 = 1.0
          p2 = 0.0
          do 11 j=1,n
            p3 = p2
            p2 = p1
            p1 = ((2.0*j-1.0)*z*p2-(j-1.0)*p3)/j
 11       continue
          pp = n*(z*p1-p2)/(z*z-1.0)
          z1 = z
          z = z1-p1/pp
          if (dabs(z-z1).gt.eps) go to 1
          x(i) = xm-xl*z
          x(n+1-i) = xm+xl*z
          w(i) = 2.0*xl/((1.0-z*z)*pp*pp)
          w(n+1-i) = w(i)
 12   continue
      return
      end subroutine
```

For your information and if I made a good job, i translated this into Matlab and seems that there is no problem with the loops in the routine.

Comment: Most probably the the correct thing is execution. I basically mean that I run the code, and "this run" to get the output does not stop. So should be execution then. I will modify the title. Apologies for any confusion

Comment: debugging 101 start throwing write statements in to see whats going on. `write(*,*)z,z1,eps` just before the `if..goto` would be a good start.  ( Look up `do while` while you are at it .. )

Comment: the routine works fine, i tried this already. But for some reason once I put it on the loops, as indicated above, the execution does not stop. This what I do not understand. In order to check whether there was a problem with the loop within the routine, I also converted the code to matlab, and it works fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of an extended comment:

One thing I notice is you tagged this as fortran77 but in fact it will not compile if this is indeed an f77-type external subroutine (ie. not in a module/contains construct) because you use `implicit none` but fail to declare `i` in the subroutine.

( There are numerous other post-f77 syntax features in there as well. )

So...assuming this subroutine is internal (ie. lives within contains in the calling routine) the `i` here :

```
 do 12 i=1,m
```

is the same `i` from the scope of the calling routine, ie. you are effectively using the same variable for two nested loops.

This is obviously an illegal thing to do, and I must say I'm disturbed to see that gfortran silently compiles such and runs off in an endless loop.. (!?!)

I'd suggest moving the subroutine to a module or simply making it external if you think this is the case. Then the compiler will flag your failure to declare `i`

### example

both gfortran and ifort compile this without warnings:

```
  implicit none
  integer j
  do j = 1,2
     call x()
  enddo
  contains
  subroutine x()
  implicit none
  do j=3,4
     write(*,*)j
  enddo
  end subroutine
  end
```

the gfortran version runs away endlessly printing 3,4,3,4. The intel version writes 3,4 just once (ie not what you might expect either)

declaring `j` in the subroutine fixes it of course..

Comment: George, you are amazing dude. You saved my desperation with fortran, since i had no idea in general from programming. Just for the records, the original code is in f77 and indeed the routine was an external one. But because I could not compile it, I thought to do it as an internal one. Declaring all the time things in this programming language might become so frustrating. A big thank you.

Comment: glad to help - usually explicit type declaration is your friend, saving you from that type of mistake. It seems to me the compilers ought to be able to flag this one too.

Comment: Which compilers do you suggest? With the exception of Visual FORTRAN which is expensive what do you recommend ? I used, Plato and the Simply FORTRAN, but none of those flagged this out.

Comment: neither gfortran nor ifort picked this up either. I wouldn't go paying for another compiler on account of this fairly obscure issue.